# Getting Error: Unable to find standalone executable Please download IEDRIVERSERVER

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver and trying to launch IE ( version 11) , which is the default browser. I would think that the browser should simply launch based On the code in my step def (see below). I am not using the selenium-webdriver.  All the same I have tried putting the driver in the path and changed the protected mode on the IE browser. Nothing seems to work.  Any thoughts ?  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Step-def

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir'`
require 'rspec'
require 'cucumber'
#require 'selenium-webdriver'

Given(/^On the Lumber Trading Screen, select a facility grouping that has a facility that uses Availability \(I used facility_Id 354\)$/) do
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
@browser.window.maximize
@browser.goto 'http:xxxxxxxxx'

Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'watir-webdriver'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'watir'
gem 'rubygems'

env.rb

equire 'watir'
require 'cucumber'
require 'watir-webdriver'
#require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rubygems'

#require 'rake'
#desc 'Run Cucumber features and generate an HTML summary, JUnit XML and a plain text log'
#
#Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
#
#  t.cucumber_opts =
#      "--no-color"
#      "--format junit    -o log/",
#      "--format html     -o log/features.html",
#      "--format pretty"]

TEST_DATA_DIR = "./features/test_data"
if ENV["HEADLESS"]
  INDEX_OFFSET = 0
  WEBDRIVER = false
else

end
```

Comment: Watir-Webdriver is just a wrapper around Selenium-Webdriver - ie you are using Selenium-Webdriver. Are you sure you put the IE driver in a folder that is in your path?

Comment: understood thanks for your response.
The IEDRIVERserver is unzipped and in the following path

c:\xxxx\xxxx\Ruby193\GP

Added the variables as follows

variable name: IEDRIVERSERVER
VARIABLE value: c:\xxxx\xxxx\Ruby193\GP;

Comment: Restarted  the computer and  I h=get the same error

Comment: Try declaring the variable right to the .exe like this c:\xxxx\xxxx\Ruby193\GP\IEDRIVER.exe

Comment: Resolved ... Works like a charm. Slow but it works . Thanks all!!??

Comment: Somebody should post an answer and accept it so this doesn't show up in answers:0 queries.  Thank you.